# How can I set existing HREF links to open in a new window with javascript

Tags: javascript

[edit] I am NOT using jquery in this app.

Looking for a way to force preexisting links to open in a new window. But I only want to Apply this behavior to links appearing in a specific div element that has a classname but no ID

Comment: _I am NOT using jquery in this app._ ... Well, you should.  It'll make your life much easier.

Comment: It may make life easier but it's not necessary.

Comment: I never said it's necessary.  Similarly, no-one ever said that a bed is necessary.

Comment: I'm fine with using jquery, depending on the app, but it seems a bit of a stretch to hang it on as an afterthought, just so Its simpler to do this one task. I think for this app, I'd rather just add an ID to the div element, along with FF's solution and call it a day ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using jQuery, first get the  element that you want to apply it to.

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var myDiv = null;

for (var j = 0; j < allDivs.length; j++) {
    var divClass = allDivs[j].getAttribute('class');
    if (divClass != null && divClass.indexof(THE_CLASS_NAME) >= 0) {
        myDiv = allDivs[i];
        var allAnchors = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < allAnchors.length; a++) {
            allAnchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `allAnchors[i]`.

Comment: Notice how much simpler the jQuery way is.  (This is the simplest cross-browser way to do it without jQuery or a similar library

Comment: I'm not saying jQuery is a bad idea I'm just saying that it's not necessary. That also doesn't mean he can't use any other library of his choice, but I'm giving him an answer without dependence on a third party.

Comment: @FF > I'm getting Error: divClass.indexof is not a function, changed it to indexOf which resolved that error. Now getting myDiv is undefined ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$('div.SomeClass a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can do like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.ClassNameOfTheDiv a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('www.yoursite.org')>Your Site Opens in a new window</a>
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question.

Comment: welcome to SO cymorg, but as SLaks pointed out please try to make sure that you are answering the actual question being asked :)